# Using jQuery with CSS in Drupal 7 "Zen" theme

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, drupal-theming

I'm editing  the "Zen" theme in Drupal 7. And that's the problem:

```
 (function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {        
         alert("xuy");
         $("#navigation ul.links li").hover(function() {
         alert("xuy");
    });
```

The first alert is working well, but there is no alert on hover. I've got this class in CSS.  Even

```
 $("a").hover(function() { 
          alert("xuy"); 
    });
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like the code is executing before the DOM is ready. Take a look at the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Comment: nope. it's ok. `$(document).ready(function () { alert("piska"); });` still working.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer before, but I was talking about needing to move the event handler binding (the `.hover()` call) in to the DOM ready, so that the elements it's trying to bind the event handler to actually exist when the code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a little funky to me. Shouldn't you be using drupal behaviors in drupal 7? (yes you should).

```
Drupal.behaviors.mybehavior = function(context, settings){
  $('#navigation ul.links li').hover(function() {
    alert('xuy');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should determine $ 
like

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mybehavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings){
       //you code goes here
       //$ will work inside this function
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```